# Mouse cursor or keyboard response in a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have such a desire for a web page. A text search box is initially placed in the center of the html page. When a user visits this page and click the text field in the search box to type something, this search box is now placed at the top of the page, and the user can start to type. The layout and position of all other elements or components on this page doesn't change. The HTML of this search box is as follows:

```
<input type="text" />
```

How to realize this? JavaScript? Any information or pointer would be very helpful. I am not very familiar with JavaScript, but good resources for the solution would be appreciated.

Comment: You can do this with listening the change event of text box. Add class with css like `position:fixed; top:0;`

Comment: Is this what you look for? https://jsfiddle.net/pevuLt20/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a pure CSS solution:

```css
#box, #button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  
    -webkit-transition: top 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: top 2s;  
    -webkit-transition-delay: 99999s; /* Safari */
    transition-delay: 99999s;
}

#box:focus, #box:focus ~ #button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1s; /* Safari */
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<base target=_blank>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">

<form method=get action=http://www.google.com/search>
<input id=box type=text autocomplete=off maxlength=255 style=width:195px;margin-left:-125px />
<input id=button type=submit value=submit style=margin-left:75px />
</form>

</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, since as you click the mouse outside of the box, the box goes back to the center of the page again. That's not what I need. Please see my comments.

Comment: it seems working. The only problem with this is that, it moves upward pretty slow. Can it move instantly?

Comment: just change the following values: "-webkit-transition: top 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: top 2s;" (2 seconds is the time that the bar travels until reach the top. you can change it, example: 0.5s)

Comment: To change the delay before the move starts, change the following values: "-webkit-transition-delay: 1s; /* Safari */ transition-delay: 1s;"

Comment: What does "99999s"? which means after 9999 seconds, the box will come down?

Comment: it means it will go down after 24 hours since the last click on the bar. Your users will probably leave the website before of it.

Comment: That's no good. Let's say the user does a search on his computer, the box goes up. Then he leaves his browser alone and computer on. The next day he comes back to wake up his computer. On the same page, the box is down now. What's worse about it is that, the search box will now be embedded in some text, which are search results. Initially, the space in the center is blank so the box can be visible. But after a search, it is different. May be 9999s can be increased even further?

Comment: i think there is no limit, a day have 86400s, a week have 604800s. The current bar css position "absolute" means that it would go down in front of the content, without to mess up the layout.

Comment: A further tuning. If I want it to go to the left top and stay there after the cursor is in it, what can do that? I change it to "left:0%" in the box:focus css, it did go to the left top. But then when you click mouse again, it goes to top center, and doesn't stay at top left.

Comment: in this case you must to add the 'left' alteration to the 'transition' aswell: "    -webkit-transition: top 2s, left 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: top 2s, left 2s; "

Comment: since now you have changed the 'left' percentage, I recomend you to change the in-line "margin-left" values of the html tags (inside the form).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a css selector `:selected`

```
.element1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  /* or whatever styles to move it to center*/
}


.element1:focus {
  position: static;
  border: 1px solid red;
  outline: none!important;
  /* or whatever styles to move it to top*/
}
```

Check the following JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jefsrp70/1/

**Update**

Based on your comment, I think you need JavaScript or Jquery. Look at the new fiddle, Updated Code: https://jsfiddle.net/jefsrp70/2/

Basically, you need to add another class and apply the styles to the new class,

```
$('.element1:not(.moved)').on('focus', function (ev) {
    $(ev.target).addClass('moved');
});
```

Comment: so I just use this with using JavaScript? Can you be a little specific about how to you use thin in HTML?

Comment: You mean without using JavaScript? Yes, you can just give your input HTML element a class or an id. For example, you have given 'element1' as your class name for input element, then you can write two different styles, one style when there is focus inside the textbox and another style when focus is not on the text box. `.element1` styles will be applied to the input element all the time. `.element1:selected` styles will be applied only when the user focuses on this element. You can check the JSFiddle for further reference.

Comment: The problem with above code is that, when you click the mouse again, the search box comes down again. I want the box to stay in the top, once it goes there, how matter how the mouse moves. Only when the user restarts the browser, the search box will be placed in the center.

Comment: Hi, Kishor, where to put the new JavaScript?  in html page?